# Article "promoted to front page" also displays all images of featured slideshow

Tags: views

Currently using Shinbun theme and Drupal 7 (based on an existing site, as required for a project) and was struggling to create a slideshow of selected images, which I finally managed on the article pages with Views Slideshow module. 
[image]
Works fine for all Article pages, using one image as static or more as a slideshow. Unfortunately, when using more as a slideshow and selecting the option "promoted to front page" and "sticky on top", to project the article in the front page, it also displays the images of the articles... And in the case of our slideshow, it shows them all, one under the other.

[image: here's how the front page appears]

What I would like to do is, preferably, find a workaround to display only ONE of the slideshow images, OR show none of them.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear from your question or the accompanying screenshot, but perhaps you are using a different view mode and/or Views display for the Article content type on the front page, and not actually using your slideshow Views display at all in that context. To be sure, I'd need more info:

- In what context is the slideshow working? (Sounds to me like it works when you view an Article node)
- In what context is the slideshow not working? (Sounds to me like this happens when an Article is displayed in a Views Block display on the homepage)

If this is the case, then you're not using Views Slideshow to display the article in this context, and you may also be using a different view mode (i.e., Teaser) to display the Article on the homepage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am fairly new to drupal, I usually do things more manually, so my experience with this is very limited. The slideshow feature I used was based on [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/sXh8Ng9QNaA). What I can use is very limited as well (strictly on a drupal 7 theme). The slideshow worked as displayed in the article page, but not the other content types. The problem is that, as I have inserted a number of images to be in the slideshow, they all appear as pictured in the front page. So I would like to opt out of the images for this article, or select to show only one.